# Get Team Site Shared Documents List Id reliably

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

Is it possible to get the list Id for the Shared Documents reliably. Currently I list all the lists and look for the following entry. "Shared_x0020_Documents" This is fine when look at english sites.

[image]

If its a dutch site you get the following:
[image]

I need a reliable way to identify the Shared Documents list across any language.

I would like to do this via CSOM or via the REST API

Comment: With the server side object model you could either check myList.TitleResource.GetValueForUICulture(lcid) which would return the localized title for the locale of your choice or use SPUtility.GetLocalizedString to get the actual list name from the SharePoint resource file (I think it should be in owscore.resx). See if any is available via CSOM, I am in a hurry now and can't really check. I will try to see if I can think something more specific later.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to do  this against SharePoint Online and can't see TitleResource.

Comment: @Webfort did you ever find a solution

Comment: @w00t unfortunately I didn't find a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I usually get it from the URL displayed when in the library settings screen.

```
http://YourSite.com/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=%7B2AE2F877%2D46E0%2D401E%2DBAD2%2D36332A23880F%7D
```

Don't forget to remove the %7B and the %7D as they are ( & )

Comment: Sorry I need do this via csom